# Search using REST endpoints on two different columns with OR condition in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, search-criteria

I'm using Magento v2.3 and using **API** to search products.

Following is the search criteria code.

```
'searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]': 'name',
'searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]': '%test%',
'searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]': 'like',
'searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][field]': 'meta_keyword',
'searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][value]': '%test%',
'searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][conditionType]': 'like',
'searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][field]': 'status',
'searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][value]': '1',
'searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][conditionType]': 'eq',
```

I want something like this (OR condition between two different columns).

> WHERE name like '%test%' OR meta_keyword like '%test%'

But above code doesn't give me desired results.

I have gone through documentation of Magento here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html

but the examples shown in above link are "OR conditions on same column".

Thanks in advance!